# Convergence mode with inputs and functions varying in tandem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits-and-convergence

Given a sequence $(f_n)$ of functions between metric spaces, let's say that $f_n$ "converges flexibly" to $f$ if, whenever $x_n \to x$ is a convergent sequence of inputs, it follows that $f_n(x_n) \to f(x)$.

Questions:

1. Does this have a standard name?
2. Does this convergence mode corresponding to some metric/topology on a function space?

Comments:

- Continuity of a single function, stated sequentially, can be thought of as "Convergent inputs with fixed function yields convergent outputs."  Pointwise convergence can be thought of as "Fixed input with convergent functions yields convergent outputs."  In some sense, this is trying to combine the two.
- The Skorohod metric on the space of cadlag functions is similar in spirit, but (I think) not quite the same thing.

Elementary results I've been able to figure out:

1. Flexible convergence implies pointwise convergence.  (The constant sequence $x, x, \dots$ converges to $x$.)
2. Uniform convergence implies flexible convergence ***if*** the limit function $f$ is continuous.  (Given $x_n \to x$ and $\epsilon > 0$, choose $\delta$ corresponding to $\epsilon/2$ for the continuity of $f$ at $x$, then choose $N$ such that $\|f_n - f\| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for $n \geq N$ and also such that $|x_n-x| < \delta$ for $n \geq N$.)  However, this implication need not hold if $f$ is not continuous.  (For instance, let $f$ be any discontinuous function, $f_n = f$ for all $n$, and $x_n \to x$ any sequence for which $f(x_n) \not \to f(x)$.)
3. Flexible convergence implies uniform convergence ***if*** the limit function $f$ is continuous ***and*** the domain is compact.  (Contrapositively, suppose uniform convergence fails.  Pick an $\epsilon > 0$ and points $x_n$ for which $|f_n(x_n) - f(x)| \geq \epsilon$ for all $n$.  Let $x_{n_k} \to x$ be a convergente subsequence.  Then $f(x_{n_k}) \to f(x)$ by continuity, but $|f_{n_k}(x_{n_k}) - f(x)| \geq \epsilon$ for all $k$, so that $f(x_{n_k})$ cannot converge to $f(x)$.  Thus flexible convergence fails.)  Without these hypotheses, examples like the characteristic functions of $[n,n+1]$ or $[0,1/n]$ exhibit flexible convergence without uniform convergence.

Comment: If $f_n \to f$ in the flexble sense, then **necessarily** $f$ is continuous: let $x_n$ be any converging sequence, you can find (by pointwise convergence) a strictly increasing sequence $k_n$ such that $d(f_{k_n}(x_n), f(x_n)) < 1/n$. And hence flexible convergence implies that $f(x_n) \to f(x)$. With this my guess is that flexible convergence is the same as locally uniform convergence, restricted to the category of continuous functions.